# git aws.push: No module named boto

Tags: django, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto

i'm trying to follow the tutorial: [deploy django on aws Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html)

when i'm doing the Step 6's substep 5:

```
git aws.push
```

I get a ImportError message:

```
(tryhasinenv)Lee-Jamess-MacBook-Pro:tryhasin h0925473$ git aws.push
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push", line 21, in <module>
    from aws.dev_tools import * 
  File "/Users/h0925473/tryhasin_root/tryhasin/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line 5, in <module>
    import boto
ImportError: No module named boto
```

I have no idea what to do. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354411/awss-elastic-beanstalk-not-using-my-virtualenv-no-module-named-boto/27308707#27308707

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On OSX I found that `pip install boto` did not resolve the issue.
The problem was that python was not pointing to the pip installation.
`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
resolved this for me.

Comment: I issued the export for PYTHONPATH but I still get the dreaded boto error when trying to aws.push. When I do go ahead and try to do the pip install boto I get:
      `File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
...
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.1`

Comment: Okay, I fixed this by cloning boto from git and installing that way.

Comment: Adding PYTHONPATH also worked for me - I just had to make sure that I was using the right path for the tutorial (e.g. on a mac, after following all the tutorial instructions, the path was /private/tmp/djangodev/lib/python2.7/site-packages).

Comment: Hi, everytime I use aws.push I have to re-enter the export path. is there someway around this please? cheers

Comment: My Mac OS X install did not come with pip.  I found pip in `/usr/local/aws/bin/`.  So I ran `pip install boto` from there. `git aws.push` still didn't work.  I did a `which python` and saw it wasn't using the python in `/usr/local/aws/bin`.  So I added `/usr/local/aws/bin` to my PATH in my ~/.bash_profile.  git aws.push is working now with AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3.

Comment: @PhilHudson - Note that you can set the variable globally (at least for your user account) by adding it to your `~/.bash_profile`; every time Terminal is opened, it reads that file.

Answer (score 17):

I solved this separately by running:

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

This uses the default python package installer to install PIP

```
$ sudo pip install boto
```

I needed Admin rights to add boto (I don't know if thats right or not).

Then ran `$ eb start`

Comment: This will install the boot for me and solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Did you `pip freeze > requirements.txt` after you ran `pip install boto`?

You need to update your `requirements.txt` after each time you install a new python package locally to ensure your AWS instance has all the required packages as well.

EDIT:

In case you aren't the one who wrote `boto` in, you'll need to install it and then pip freeze it yourself.

Try running the following commands:

```
pip install boto
pip freeze > requirements.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Added boto"
git aws.push
```

Comment: it's because didn't install boto.
After I installed boto,git add, git commit and git aws.push, and eb status --verbose is green and ready, but I can still go to the EB default welcome page.
It should go to django's welcome page instead.
And i've set all the config and edit the setting.py according to the tutorial

Comment: yes, i ran them all. What information should i provide, so it can help you understand what i did wrong?

Comment: i don't get the boto error, but can't go to django's welcome page, it keeps go to eb's welcome page instead

Comment: Are you able to see the Django welcome page on your local computer? i.e. after you run `python manage.py runserver`? Did you do `django-admin.py startproject mysite` and all of that?

Comment: i can't run python manage.py runserver, the message is "Unknown command: 'runserver'", but i'm sure i'm at the level of manage.py.
and i did django-admin.py startproject mysite before i set eb

Comment: Run 'python manage.py help' and see what exception you're getting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51451/discussion-between-user2988464-and-alex)

Comment: I am getting the same "no module named boto" error. I ran all of these commands and can see boto saved in my requirements file, which was successfully committed, but I'm still getting the error. What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Ansible and fixed it using:

```
sudo apt install python-boto
```

Comment: this was the only answer that worked for me running Ubuntu Xenial via Vagrant and VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

I am using python3. So I had to use the following command for `PYTHONPATH` to point to site-packages dir

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ubuntu, try this out:-

```
sudo apt install python-boto3
```

Should work.