# AWS aws.push ImportError: No module named boto in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

in order to deploy a Ruby on Rails app in AWS with Ubuntu.

Everything went ok (I can run my app in local), until the final step. When I run aws.push I get next error.

```
   roberto@ubuntu:~/dev/myapp$ git aws.push
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push", line 21, in <module>
    from aws.dev_tools import * 
  File "/home/roberto/dev/myapp/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line 5, in <module>
    import boto
ImportError: No module named boto
```

I have read this post [git aws.push: No module named boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297719/git-aws-push-no-module-named-boto) and run:

```
pip install boto
pip freeze > reqIuirements.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Added boto"
git aws.push
```

But still the same result.

**UPDATE:** 
I think the problem is related to my python versions.
When I run `which python`  I get /usr/bin/python. If I do ls this folder I see python, python2, python2.7, python3, python3.4.

When I run `python` I get:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I don't know what to do.

The problem was the first boto installation it didn't work due to permissions problems, and I didn't realize. I ran `sudo pip install boto` and everything went OK this time.

Comment: I had the same problem, I fixed it doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354411/awss-elastic-beanstalk-not-using-my-virtualenv-no-module-named-boto/27308707#27308707

Comment: just incase this helps people -- I also used: 
```sudo pip install boto``` to install, but the permissions were then wrong - and had to
```chmod 755``` on the installed packages to fix

Answer (score -10, accepted):

See my own comments in the post above.

Answer (score 40):

What happened is that the eb command line interface available in that specific AWS tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html) does not provide the latest version of boto.

When you did

```
pip install boto
```

you installed the latest version from https://github.com/boto/boto which solved the issue.

Answer (score 20):

If on OSX w/o pip installed:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install boto
```

Comment: It's my pleasure Sinclair!

Answer (score 8):

Make sure when you install Python modules that you look at the output to verify that the install happened properly.  On Mac/Linux I had to run sudo to get boto to install properly.

```
sudo pip install boto
```

Answer (score 4):

I had face same issue with `boto` installation on Mac OS High Sierra :

`boto` required `PYTHONPATH` to be set in system.
First install boto :

```
sudo pip install boto
```

After installation it will return path where `boto` is installed in logs. Use same path to add export as `PYTHONPATH`

> Requirement already satisfied: boto in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.48.0)

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

After adding `PYTHONPATH` python will able to detect `boto` module in system.

Comment: bingo - may devops no longer be hacky one day - until then, thank goodness for answers which are like cool water upon the head of a mac user

Answer (score 3):

If you are still having issues after downloading boto, make sure your script is able to reach your site-packages by defining the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing these 3 steps helps in cases there are any error with installing pip/python first.

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py 
$ sudo pip install boto
```

Or if you are on Mac, then you can try installing Python3.

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2-macosx10.6.pkg then, Install it (UI way if you want to).

```
$ sudo pip3 install boto
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to run:

```
python -m pip install --user boto
```

`pip` defaults to installing Python packages to a system directory (such as `/usr/local/lib/python3.X`). 
This requires root access.

`--user` makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges. Read more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-of-pip-install-user).

(*) Make sure you not use `pip install --user pkg_name` inside a virtual environment. Read more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user/56948334#56948334).